# How to edit WebM video files on Mac?

Tags: video, video-editing

[Join.me exports screen recordings in WebM format](http://help.join.me/knowledgebase/articles/205770-find-play-edit-your-recordings). I can play WebM files using VLC but I can't edit them. Searching for a solution brings up hundreds of spamware 'video converters'.

Is there a simple way to edit WebM video files on MacOS?

Comment: Do you want to *edit* or convert the file?

Comment: @Allan both. If I convert, I can edit easily in iMovie etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually convert your WebM video directly in VLC:

- Open the conversion screen with <kbd>Shift-Cmd-S</kbd>
- Drag the WebM video into the screen
- Select a target format your video editor supports
- Click on "Save as file"

Afterwards open the generated file in the video editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I searched 'webm' on the Mac App Store and found this free app:

4Video Quick Video Converter
https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/4video-quick-video-converter/id765334104?mt=12

And it worked.

The settings are tricky, you have to add the file, then click the small MPEG4 icon to the right to change the output settings.